# how can I fix MetaMask Failed to fetch error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ethereum, web3js, metamask

I call the contract.methods.ownerOf 2500 times then I got the MetaMask - RPC Error: Failed to fetch. But I call the method about 200 times, then there's no error. how can I fix the error?
(ownerOf is etherscan contract interface)

here's my code.

```
export async function list() {
  const MAX_TOKEN_ID = 2500;
  const web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider ||'http://localhost:8080');
  const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(ERC721ABI as AbiItem[], CONTRACT);
  const list = new Set<number>();
  let result: object;
  for (let tokenId = 1; tokenId <= MAX_TOKEN_ID; tokenId++) {
    const address = await contract.methods.ownerOf(tokenId).call();
    list.add(address);
  }
  result = Array.from(list).map((item) => ({address: item}));
  return result;
}
```

and my error
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Probably your MetaMask enabled only on your current site? So *Page access* is set to *Run on click*.

This case one solution is to enable it *Always run on all sites*.

Or adding `https://proxy.metafi.codefi.network/*` in extension's *Site access* solved here.

Answer (score 1):

To make a large number of JSON-RPC requests you need to [host your own node](https://twitter.com/moo9000/status/1370323189486784513) or purchase [as a node as a service](https://ethereumnodes.com/).

RPC requests are not free and someone must pay for them. If you are not paying yourself, then whoever is serving you has all their right to cut you off.

Comment: thank you so much..I didn't know RPC requests are not free..  then I have one more question. I want to get holder list of my token in etherscan. do you know how to get holder list efficiently?

Comment: If you have another question please open a new question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

On extension settings choose `Site access: On all sites` then it will work